# how to create a jquery counter function for modal switching

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, click, counter

i got the following problem, i would like to create a counter function to switch between modals so i can re-use the function on multiple pages, i'm fighting my way trough the internet but can't find the solution, i tried multiple options, but it only switched trough the first 2 modals, also when i check the log, my counter variable don't get past 1 (first click).

i started with this

```
        var counter = 0; 
        var step = 1;
        var prev = 0;   

        $( document ).ready(function() {

            $('.button-'+counter).click(function() {
                    counter++;   
                    prev = counter - step;

                    $('.window-'+prev).modal('hide');
                    $('.window-'+counter).modal('show');
                    console.debug(counter, prev);

            });


            //$('.modal-header > .close').click(function() {
            //    counter = 0;
            //});

        });
```

then after some research i ended up with this, but it does exactly the same thing

```
    var counter = 0; 
    var step = 1;
    var prev = 0;   

    $( document ).ready(function() {  
        $('#addproductnext').each(function() {
            $(this).on('click', function() {
                counter++;   
                prev = counter - step;
                console.log(counter, prev);
                if($('#addproductwindow').hasClass('window-'+prev)) {
                $('.window-'+prev).modal('hide');
                $('.window-'+counter).modal('show');

                };
        });
    });
```

This is my quick fix for now, but i dont think it's neat

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    $('.button-0').click(function() {
        $('.window-0').modal('hide');
        $('.window-1').modal('show');
    });
     $('.button-1').click(function() {
        $('.window-1').modal('hide');
        $('.window-2').modal('show');
    });

     $('.button-2').click(function() {
        $('.window-2').modal('hide');
        $('.window-3').modal('show');  
    });

    $('.button-3').click(function() {
        $('.window-3').modal('hide');
        $('.window-4').modal('show');  
    });


//$('.modal-header > .close').click(function() {
//    counter = 0;
//});

});
```

Here is what my html looks like (php function)

```
<div class="modal fade window-' . $number . '" id="' . $name . '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="' . $name . '" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="' . $backdrop . '">
        <div class="modal-dialog ' . $class . '" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="deletemessage">' . $header .'</strong></h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
BODY
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Give the all the buttons the same class like `button-modal` or something. Then in 2nd piece of code change `#addprofuctnext` to `.button-modal` and remove the if statement. Try that let me know how it goes

Comment: thank you my friend! wish i would posted this earlier, it would have saved me a lot of hours.

Comment: I have posted my answer so that people in future can see the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button class="button-modal">Button 1</button>
<button class="button-modal">Button 2</button>
<button class="button-modal">Button 3</button>

<script>
var counter = 0; 
var step = 1;
var prev = 0;   

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button-modal').each(function() {
        counter++;
        prev = counter - step;
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            $('.window-'+prev).modal('hide');
            $('.window-'+counter).modal('show');
        };
    });
});
</script>
```

Give the buttons the same class like 'button-modal'. Then use the class to get the buttons and for each of them add a click listener to hide your previous modal and show your next modal.